# Powerline not display properly on alacritty

Tags: gnome-shell

I installed the powerline plugin from [b-ryan/powerline-shell: A beautiful and useful prompt for your shell](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell)

I works properly on gnome-shell

[image]

However, it failed to display correctly on alacritty terminal 
[jwilm/alacritty: A cross-platform, GPU-accelerated terminal emulator](https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty)

What's the problem it might be?

[image]

Comment: How did you install alacritty?

Comment: serious? or try to hint me something? @DKBose

Comment: No, I'm interested in it but the only ppa I found was based on Pop OS. But kitty is in the 18.10 and 19.04 repos. That's also GPU-based.

Comment: Try to open an issue on the Alacritty github repo, you will get more answers there

Answer (score 4):

## install a nerd font

### manual

Install this font:
[JetBrainsMono](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v2.1.0/JetBrainsMono.zip)

### automated

This script will download and install 3 fonts (by saving them to a fonts dir

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function is_mac() {
  # local uname="$(uname -a)"
  [[ "$uname_" =~ Darwin ]] && return
  false
}

function git-repo-release(){
    repo=${1? must provide a repo ex casonadams/walh }

    version=$(curl \
        -sSL "https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/releases/latest" \
        | grep '"tag_name":' \
        | sed -E 's/.*"([^"]+)".*/\1/'\
    )

    echo $version
}

function install_fonts(){
    local repo="ryanoasis/nerd-fonts"
    local version=$(git-repo-release $repo)
    local _dir="${HOME}/.local/share/fonts"
    local url

    if is_mac; then
        _dir="${HOME}/Library/Fonts"
    fi

    mkdir -p $_dir
    pushd $_dir

    rm -rf "${_dir}/*"

    # FONTS TO INSTALL
    fonts=(
        "FiraCode"
        "JetBrainsMono"
        "SourceCodePro"
    )

    for font in "${fonts[@]}"
    do
        url="https://github.com/${repo}/releases/download/${version}/${font}.tar.xz"
        curl -sSL $url | tar -Jvx
    done

    popd
}

install_fonts
```

## Setup alacritty

Grab this file alacritty.yml from github repo.

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/alacritty
curl -L https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/alacritty.yml -o ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml
```

Then update the alacritty.yml file with the example below

```
vi ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml
```

```
# Font configuration (changes require restart)
font:
  # copy fonts to ~/.local/share/fonts (linux)
  # copy fonts to ~/Library/Fonts (mac)
  normal:
    # family: "JetbrainsMono Nerd Font"
    # family: "SauceCodePro Nerd Font"
    family: "FiraCode Nerd Font"
  size: 16
```

Comment: `JetBrains Mono Medium Nerd Font Complete.ttf` maps to `family: "JetBrainsMono Nerd Font"`